# Unknown library get imported using an XCFramework in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, xcframework

I was following apple XCFramework video about *Binary Frameworks in Swift* in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/) and that video they jump to definition of an XCFramework and it shows just `Import UIKit` at timeline of 4:36 so far so good, I just created and followed same way, but I am seeing some extra thing that I did not use it when I was building my XCFramework, what is `import _Concurrency` I just used `import SwiftUI` in my framework, how ever after building my XCFramework and using it in a test project I see this:

[image]

**How ever my source code was this:**

[image]

So why I am seeing `import _Concurrency` after building and import to test project? I do not need it why it must be there? am I doing something wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

public var iOS_EmojiFrameworkVersion: String = "1.0.0"
public var iOS_DeploymentVersion: String = "13.0.0"

public struct EmojiView: View {
    
    public init() {}
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        return Text("").font(Font.system(size: 150.0))
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this refers to the Swift Concurrency support library. If you are targeting iOS 14 or earlier, your app must include this support library. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But I chose iOS 13 in my framework inside Xcode setting also iOS 13 in test project, still seeing that unknown library.

Comment: @ioscoder the concurrency support library will be imported for iOS 13 and 14. UIKit uses this library too.

Comment: @Tadreik: But why there is need to it? `Import SwiftUI` is just enough for me.